# How to create a loop that pushes data from array into 2 stacks but stops after 7 iterations?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing homework and have been given some data in a text file. I have to feed the data into 2 stacks but they can only hold 7 data at the time.

example data t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14

```
Stack<String> lift1 = new Stack<>();
Stack<String> lift2 = new Stack<>();
String[] cargo = ecf.getArray("ConstructionData6.txt");

for(int k=0; k<cargo.length; k++) 
        {
           lift1.push(cargo[k]);

        }


        System.out.println("Lift Cargo: ");
        System.out.println("lift1: " +lift1);
        System.out.println("lift2: " +lift2);
```

Output would be :

lift1: [t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7]
lift2: [t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14]

Comment: Pseudo-code: `if k < 7 add to lift1 else add to lift2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a homework, I'm not going to provide any Java code, just pseudo-code.

The example data set has 14 items, but could it have 15? 25? A good solution would be dynamic enough to handle the variation. I suggest a collection of stacks, with each stack in the collection holding no more than 7 items.

```
// Again, this is not actually Java, just pseudo code

// Create a place to put your restructured data
Collection theStacks = new Collection();
theStacks.push( new Stack<>() );

Stack<> whichStack = null;
String[] cargo = ecf.getArray("ConstructionData6.txt");

for (int k=0; k<cargo.length; k++) {

    // Pick the correct stack to put stuff in
    if (the last stack in theStacks  has length > 7) {
        // If the most recent stack has 7 things in it, make a new one
        theStacks.push( new Stack<>() );
    }
    whichStack = the last stack in theStacks;

    // Push it, push it real good
    whichStack.push(cargo[k]);
}
```

Even better would be to replace the "magic number" 7 with a variable or constant.

Comment: I can only use two stacks for this, I have another text file with 18 items and I have to move those items into the 2 stacks and then into one queue. How would I make it so that it keeps feeding the items into stacks when one stack unloads into the queue?

Comment: @PatrykPierzgalski, That's a rather more complicated question. How/when you unload the stack to the queue depends on logic you haven't shared. You'd have to more fully explain that issue, perhaps in a different question.